# Capturar Timeout em requisição GET

Tags: golang

Em meu código eu possuo uma "tentativa" de capturar o `timeout` do método `Get` do pacote `http` mas por algum motivo o erro não é capturado e um `panic` é exibido dizendo:

> Get http://domain.site.com.br/endpoint: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
>
> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Essa requisição acontece dentro de uma `goroutine`.

```
request, err := http.NewRequest(method, endpoint, bytes.NewReader(data)) // data é nil
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

client := &http.Client{
    Timeout: 2 * time.Second,
}

response, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return nil, Error{Message: err.Error(), Code: response.StatusCode}
}
defer response.Body.Close()

// TODO: For some reason the timeout handle is not working
if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() {
    fmt.Println("timeout!") // não exibe a mensagem
    return nil, Error{Message: "timeout.", Code: http.StatusRequestTimeout}
}
```

Ao retornar o `Error` eu faço um type checking com:

```
if err, ok := err.(commom.Error); ok {
    close(tube) // close the channel
    w.WriteHeader(err.Code)
    response.Encode(err)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontecia porque outro erro era verificado antes do erro de `timeout`

```
response, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return nil, Error{Message: err.Error(), Code: response.StatusCode}
}
```

No caso acima a variável `response` não possuía `StatuCode` porque o `client` encerrou a request devido ao tempo de `timeout`.

A ordem correta da verificação de erros é:

```
response, err := client.Do(request)
if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() {
    return nil, Error{Message: "timeout.", Code: http.StatusRequestTimeout}
}
defer response.Body.Close()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return nil, Error{Message: err.Error(), Code: response.StatusCode}
}
```